# How to deploy a Django backend and Flutter frontend web app

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework, deployment

I've been working on a web application that uses Django REST Framework and Django channels in the backend and has a Flutter frontend. It works successfully when tested locally, but my question was how would I deploy this:

- What server is most appropriate for this application? (it should be free as this is just a personal project I've been testing)
- Do I need to deploy the frontend and backend separately?
- Are there any online resources I can refer to, to help me in this process?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it only for your personal use you could use https://www.heroku.com/free to host you backend.
You could use this [guide](https://realpython.com/django-hosting-on-heroku/)

Yes, you should deploy them seperately.
Since in your specific case the django application is only used to hold the data, provide a REST API and sockets.